# Moving from Analogue PBX to digital VoIP?

Tags: voip, telephony, telephone, softphone

I don't even know if this belongs here?. If not, do let me know.

So we have an analogue Alkatel PABX system in our little office. We have extensions, direct lines and PBX lines.

We are trying to move to a more digital/flexible way of handling the phones and I've heard good things about FreeSwitch. I have zero knowledge about it.

My biggest question is how would one handle existing phone lines with such a system. Surely there must be a way to make and receive calls from outside.

Just a help in the right direction would be fine.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't used freeswitch, but we have an asterisk system using [Sangoma A200](http://www.sangoma.com/products/hardware_products/analog_telephony/a200.html) cards to connect analogue lines to the system.

I believe this card also works with freeswitch.

You can drop [FXO](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_office) or [FXS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Foreign_exchange_station) modules into the A200, so it should do exactly what you need.

Comment: That seems exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you for filling the void. I think it does support FreeSwitch, they've mentioned that in the wiki. Is there a recommended guideline or a book for this?

Comment: I've not seen any guidelines as such, however I've found sangoma's support to be excellent. I emailed them with an issue I had, and found that they will go out of their way to help you. Perhaps drop them an email with some details of your setup, as I'm sure they will tell you exactly what you need and point you in the right direction. I've never looked at Freeswitch, so I'm not really a good person to help.